# flutter error: failed to run custom build command for libsodium-sys v0.2.7

Tags: flutter, rust, iota

I tried to use flutter with rust by flutter_rust_bridge on my MacOS, but after I added `identity_iota = { version = "0.6" }` to `Cargo.toml`, when I run the flutter, it shows

```
Error (Xcode): failed to run custom build command for `libsodium-sys v0.2.7`
```

I have tried `flutter pub add sodium_libs`, but it gave me another error after fluter run:

```
Unable to find a target named `RunnerTests` in project `Runner.xcodeproj`, did find `Runner`.
```

and it is OK if I run the rust code only.